# Analyse only highest ranked data?

Tags: r

In R, I have a list of 200 richest cities in the world. However I want to analyse data for the top 50 richest only, specifically the maximum, minimum and mean. Does anyone know how to limit this set of 200 to only the top 50? I then need to repeat it for the 50 poorest.

Comment: how is your data stored? a vector? data frame?

Comment: Please post a small sample of the data you are working with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a data.frame in which your data is stored, you can sort your data.frame via the following command (where df is your data.frame, and z is the column you wish to sort on in decreasing order):

`df[with(df, order(-z)), ]`

And to take the first fifty rows:

`df[1:50, ]`

And then you can of course access summary statistics via
`summary(df)`

Note: you may have some factor variables for which you would want to recalculate the levels after the subsetting.